# Array_push em arrays associativos multidimensionais em php

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional, array-associativo

Iniciei um array ($arrDados=array();) e agora preciso adicionar informações (array_push) de forma que possa acessar as informações posteriormente da seguinte forma:

```
colA1 = $arrDados['NumeroEmpenhoAno']['code'];
colA2 = $arrDados['NumeroEmpenhoAno']['size'];

colB1 = $arrDados['UnidadeOrc']['code'];
colB2 = $arrDados['UnidadeOrc']['size'];
```

**Qual seria o código de array_push para conseguir acessar este array na estrutura acima?**

Estou tentando o código abaixo, mas está errado:

```
$arrDados=array();
array_push($arrDados,array('NumeroEmpenhoAno' => array('code' => 0,'size' => 1)));
array_push($arrDados,array('UnidadeOrc' => array('code' => 1,'size' => 2)));
```

Da forma como estou fazendo, estou tendo que acessar da seguinte forma:

```
colA1 = $arrDados[0]['NumeroEmpenhoAno']['code'];
```

mas quero:

```
colA1 = $arrDados['NumeroEmpenhoAno']['code'];
```

Ou seja, sem índices.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa do `array_push`, você pode simplesmente fazer:

```
$arrDados = array();

$arrDados += array('NumeroEmpenhoAno' => array('code' => 0,'size' => 1));
$arrDados += array('UnidadeOrc' => array('code' => 1,'size' => 2));
```

---

Entretanto uma das formas mais comuns de fazer:

```
$arrDados = array();

$arrDados['NumeroEmpenhoAno'] = array('code' => 0,'size' => 1);
$arrDados['UnidadeOrc'] = array('code' => 1,'size' => 2);
```

---

Ambos poderão ser acessados por `$arrDados['UnidadeOrc']['code']`, sem o uso do `[1]`.

[Teste isto.](https://3v4l.org/nLnfa)

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!